# Game Engine: Object with character physics shakes for some reason

Tags: game-engine, objects, physics, tracking

I have recently started to make new racing game. I downloaded and imported smooth detailed car model(.obj). I added Character physics for it, so I can add W, A, S and D controllers to it. But, after I put my Character physics on it, it began to shake, when I pressed "p". I tried to check Physics only for 1 of all materials it had, but it did not help. I even unparented cameras and lights off it, but it still shakes. And I can not add controlers that can move it(they don't work). Who can help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you are experiencing is due to the way blender calculates the collision for the quads on your ground plane. There are two ways to fix this, you can use a cube as ground instead (with collision bounds set to box), or you can set your plane's collision type to box, even though a plane is infinitely thin.

To help see the problem,
First turn on *Physics Visualization*.
This does not effect anything except what you see, so in the end it does not matter if it is on or off.
[image]

If your plane's collision bounds are not set to anything, blender automatically calculates it as if it were made up of two triangles.
[image]

However, if you set it to Box collision, This problem goes away.
[image]

If you use a thin cube instead for your ground, (with collision type set to box) this problem goes away entirely.
[image]

Another thing you can try is putting all of your logic bricks and python on a invisible low detail object, for a collision mesh, and having your detailed car as no-collision but parented to the collision mesh. Even if this alone does not remove the shaking, it will dramatically help performance.

[image]

Comment: It still shakes- does not work- I tried both of them...

Comment: OK! Here it is: https://www.dropbox.com/s/z7xeh4cucqnmd3j/6th_gear.blend?dl=0

Comment: I have no other way... Anyway, I solved it iwth using dynamic anyway... Now I got question- how do I make my car accelerate?

Comment: And, also, how do I make it look good when steering(my car currently keeps look the same when steering, but I want to make it so you can see side of car when you steer... And... If I make it accelerate, I need also inerce on it- how to make it inerce(continue its path after releasing gas)?