# Stop rigid body objects to shake on the ground

Tags: rigid-body-simulation

After cell-fractured objects explode and land on the ground, they are still moving for some reason. How to make object act more realistically so they stop moving after a while.

[image]

Comment: I think you have to set their origins to the center of mass (ctrl+alt+shift+s) :)

Comment: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21121/game-engine-object-with-character-physics-shakes-for-some-reason